# No result for keypress and click() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to add key-controls to my rails page, so that when user press space, it would automatically click on link.

```
#application.js
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 57) {
        $('#nextb').click();
        }
        }); 
     });

#in index.html
<a href="#" id="nextb" onclick="some other action">
```

But it gives me no result at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keyCode` of space (normalized through `which`) should be `32`

```
if (event.which === 32) {
    $('#nextb').click();
};
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/qR2NU/5/

Answer (score -1):

It seems to work fine for me..

But you need to add actual code in the `onclick` event.

Also the `57` key is the key <kbd>9</kbd>, space bar is 32

example at http://jsfiddle.net/eQ8na/1/

Comment: He's trying to trigger the click when the user presses the space. Not click the element and then check for the space bar.

Comment: @Senica, answer was wrong in the sense that the OP used the wrong key code. But my answer did not suggest what you say. I just proposed to use jQuery to bind the click handler instead of assigning it through the onclick attribute. My suggestion remains, as it is the proper way to handle events..